# Actual/theoretical benefits of round or flat outlet prongs

Tags: ac, connector, safety, plug, outlet

What might be the reasoning for European connectors having rounded prongs while USA and UK connectors are primarily flat pronged?

Please correct any mis-tagging.

Comment: The UK is in Europe, and we use flat prongs, though much more substantial and robust than USA's flat prongs. I have always assumed it is partly historical, and partly economics.

Answer (score 4):

Flat pins can be made more cheaply- by stamping from sheet using simple or progressive dies- than round pins, which tend to require a relatively expensive screw-machine turning operation from rod.

But really the main advantage is that whichever you pick, it fits the millions of mating receptacles in the target market.

Comment: According to [this page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91844/round-female-pin-header-vs-square-female-pin-header), round pins make better contact and a more secure fit.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is certainly a lot of historical legacy.

Round prongs can be more easily isolated, with metal only on the tip, so they are probably safer. (typical example : flat molded plastic "europlug" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europlug)

Comment: Well, It is rather that existing standards (for example US NEMA plugs) are not fit for it, but are simpler to manufacture.

Comment: You could add that to answer

Comment: @SmartManoj It's an old answser. UK plugs contacts are both square and with an insolated base. But they are thicker than NEMA plugs.