# How to make 0.1" male headers to fit into female DIP socket that has holes which are too small?

Tags: pin-headers

I recently received my largest batch yet of assembled PCBs.  The design hasn't changed since the last order, but the supplier's stock of a [socket](https://jlcpcb.com/parts/componentSearch?searchTxt=C72121) I had been using has been depleted, so I substituted a [different socket](https://jlcpcb.com/parts/componentSearch?searchTxt=C2874016).

Old socket

[image: old socket]

New socket

[image: new socket]

I've got some headers from various suppliers, such as [this](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/sullins-connector-solutions/PREC014SAAN-RC/2774840), [this](https://www.taydaelectronics.com/40-pin-2-54-mm-single-row-pin-header-strip-yellow.html), and the ones that come with the [part intended for this socket](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3800), none of which will fit into the new socket.  I've tried taking a single pin and forcing it in with a pair of pliers, but the pin just bent.

Sullins headers

[image: Sullins headers]

Tayda headers

[image: Tayda headers]

Adafruit headers

[image: Adafruit headers]

Production of my product is stalled until I can resolve this, and I live in Aotearoa New Zealand, which is about a week minimum from any supplier.  So in desperation, I'm wondering whether it would be OK to sand down the header pins to make them fit.  I realise this will remove the surface coating, and that's why I'm unsure if this is a good idea.

The product is a guitar effects pedal, and it's meant to last a long time.  I've been careful not to mate gold pins with tin sockets in the past (because this might create a kind of cell, causing corrosion), so I'm aware sanding is pretty dodgy.

I've also tried taking some other sockets I have and using them as an intermediary, but the legs of this socket are so thin they don't make a good contact with the socket on the PCB.

Piggyback socket

[image: piggyback socket]

Any other suggestions?

Would I be justified complaining to the PCB supplier that the socket they supplied is defective, given that it won't accept any of the pins I have tried?  I mean, headers are headers, right?  They are supposed to be a fairly standard fit, aren't they?

Comment: Btw, [in case you were wondering why these pin headers were suddenly more expensive](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91844/)

Comment: Why exactly is it essential for your product to jam header strips into IC sockets? Doing that for production purposes is just plain fishy.

Comment: @Lundin don't know, modularity is not a sin - quite the opposite in terms of in-field service and upgrade paths. At the size of these daughterboard, the holding force of especially the high-quality machine pins will suffice for any non-aerospace application, I'd guess - 70 g × 28 pins=1960 g (times earth acceleration) holding force for boards that weigh in the order of 10 g, that leaves a lot of room for rough handling of the encased product.

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. "modularity is not a sin" Nobody said it was, but using the wrong connectors and mechanics for whatever they are trying to achieve here might be a sin. From what I've caught up from a professional guitarist I know, guitars mainly use through-hole components for ease of maintenance indeed - nothing wrong with that as such.

Comment: That is, if the purpose of this is to create some board-to-board connection, it's the wrong solution. Use proper socket strips, or if mated height is tight, some bottom entry solution.

Comment: Unless you exactly specified the type of IC socket to be used and your manufacturer substituted different ones without your approval, I dont think you have any grounds for complaint to the manufacturer. You're using those IC sockets "off-label" as board-to-board connectors. The substitute ones are arguably better quality when used for their intended purpose, but sadly don't work for the "off-label" way you want to use them.

Comment: I might be a bit stupid here, but I know of certification heavy commercial products being used exactly like this (e.g. Jackson Labs GPSDOs): machine pins and matching socket. Where exactly does it say that these are not for this kind of application? What makes them unsuitable?

Comment: If you made the substitution, complaining to the manufacturer would be like complaining your US plug wall does not plug into a UK outlet. Machine pin sockets were never made to fit square headers. This is not a manufacturing error. Technically, even if they made the substitution you might not have a leg to stand on given the non-standard usage. Who made the substitution? You swap between you and the PCB supplier,

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. there's nothing explicitly *wrong* with using an IC socket as a board-to-board connector the way the OP wants to - but it was designed & made to be an IC socket, hence me calling it an "off-label" use. So unless the OP has explicitly told their PCB assembler to use those specific IC sockets and no others, the PCB assembler's substitution (with a better quality socket) is reasonable since their default assumption would be that the IC sockets are going to be used for their intended purpose, and not "off-label" as board-to-board connectors.

Comment: Small production run, and you can't get parts in time: easy. Desolder the sockets, solder the Ada board direct into your PCB. These sockets are really easy to get out (I haven't done this since the last century, but clipping the plastic ends helps). You're presumably manufacturing off-shore, which I can't believe is worth the effort for this sort of product. Sure, get the PCBs from China if you must, but you should (must) get someone local to assemble, even in NZ. The assembler will have a drawer full of obsolete low-reliability sockets like this.

Comment: Well with current jlcpcb pricing, offshore assembly really is extremely cheap, @EML, even for very small runs. The market for PCBA is changing rapidly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can (sadly) see, nope, sockets are not sockets!

You got precision pin sockets, do you need what is usually sold as precision turned pin headers, or precision machined pins. These are cylinders, instead of prisms.

These are all candidates, but check the individual dimensions of the pins against your socket's data sheet! (The data sheet isn't great, but does mention pins of nominally a diameter of 0.432 mm, as far as I dare interpret it)

https://www.digikey.com.au/short/3j1mdh3n

And: forget about sanding. Not going to realistically be possible.

Comment: The Mill-Max [350-10-164-00-001000](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors/headers-male-pins/314?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKYBMDMAOAbAFhAXQL5A) is one possibility. I've used them before.

Comment: Mill-Max [800 series](https://www.digikey.com.au/en/products/detail/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/800-10-014-10-001000/218686) may possibly work.

Answer (score 14):

You substituted a higher quality construction (screw machine pins) of IC socket for a cheaper kind of (stamped pins) side-wipe IC socket.

They are **IC** sockets and **neither** type is intended to fit a 0.025" square header pin, but you can often force it into the latter. The former, not so much.

You can purchase single-row female connectors that **are** intended to accept a 0.025" pin, and are gold-plated if you so desire. [Here](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/61301611821.pdf) is one at random, but there are many suppliers.

[image]

Since you appear to have the sockets already soldered in, there are thinner [round-pin headers](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/571/Catalog-1062674.pdf), but they tend to be a bit pricey, from Western sources, anyway.

[image]

Comment: I find  that it's rather common to use blade-style pin header on PCBs that are meant to be used as kind of DIP ICs, minus the I...

Comment: @ConstantineA.B.  What's an example of 'blade-style' pin header? I don't think I've noted that kind, only square and round in 0.1" pitch.

Comment: Can look this up, but just as DIP IC lead frame, stamped from a thinner sheet of metal

Answer (score 2):

The one thing that might fit is an IDC-to-DIL transition connector, which typically has thin but robust pins similar in dimension to a standard chip.

I have on occasion used that sort of thing when I've needed to make a breakout, e.g. for a logic analyzer.